# Listing all custom post types using a specific term on the said term's template page, in groups

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, templates

I have a custom tag-like taxonomy called PEOPLE registered to all post types - both the default and custom ones.

I have created a template for a single term named taxonomy-people.php and I'm intending to use it to describe a specific term and query each post type for instances of that term.

I have almost managed to do that, there's a single issue left: I don't know how to get WP_Query to show only results for the current term WITHOUT having to make a specific template for each of the terms, as I will end up having a three-digit number of terms under PEOPLE.

Here's the code that works if I specify a term. What should I replace **'people' => 'dave-lee'** with in order to use the same template for each of the terms under PEOPLE?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="eight columns" id="content">

<div class="post">

<div class="inside">

<p class="term-description">
<?php $termDescription = term_description( '', get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); if($termDescription != '') : ?> <?php echo $termDescription; ?> <?php endif; ?>
</p>


<h3>News mentioning <?php $term =   $wp_query->queried_object; echo ''.$term->name.'';?></h3>

<ul>
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'people' => 'dave-lee', 'posts_per_page' => 20 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<li class="archivepostlink"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>      </a><br />
<?php _e('Published on','jf'); ?> <?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<h3>Releases <?php $term =  $wp_query->queried_object; echo ''.$term->name.'';?> contributed to:</h3>

<ul>
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'release', 'people' => 'dave-lee', 'posts_per_page' => 20 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<li class="archivepostlink"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>    </a><br />
<?php _e('Published on','jf'); ?> <?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></li>
<?php endwhile;?>
</ul>

 <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

 <h3>Songs featuring <?php $term =  $wp_query->queried_object; echo ''.$term->name.'';?>:</h3>

<ul>
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'song', 'people' => 'dave-lee', 'posts_per_page' => 20 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<li class="archivepostlink"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
<?php _e('Published on','jf'); ?> <?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></li>
<?php endwhile;?>
</ul>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<h3>Articles, reviews and other pages mentioning <?php $term =  $wp_query->queried_object; echo ''.$term->name.'';?>:</h3>

<ul>
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'people' => 'dave-lee',     'posts_per_page' => 20 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<li class="archivepostlink"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>    </a><br />
<?php _e('Published on','jf'); ?> <?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></li>
<?php endwhile;?>
</ul>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<p>If you think <?php $term =   $wp_query->queried_object; echo ''.$term->name.'';?> was/were a part of something else that has not been listed here, drop a line.</p>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code, when working, will consume sooo much resources. When implemented in this way - throught custom page template, WordPress will call for a content of that page (1 query) and after that it will call a query for each custom post type - another 4 queries. That's a lot, really.

I would suggest you to take the advantage of [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook, where you can alter the query before any query is run. There you can specify what post types shold be queried. You can use something like this:

```
function extend_post_type( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_archive() && isset($query->query_vars['people']) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'release', 'song', 'page') );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'extend_post_type' );
```

In this way, you'll get the query full of post_types from people taxonomy. Now it's time to loop the whole query and sortout the content by post type.

I would use something like that:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ) { the_post();
        if ( get_post_type() == 'post' ){
                $posts_html .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ).'">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
        }elseif( get_post_type() == 'page' ){
                $pages_html .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ).'">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
        }elseif( get_post_type() == 'song' ){
                $songs_html .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ).'">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
        }elseif( get_post_type() == 'release' ){
                $releases_html .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ).'">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
        }
    }
    $term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var( 'people' ), 'people' );
    echo '<h2>News for "'.$term->name.'"';
    echo $posts_html;
    echo '<h2>Releases for "'.$term->name.'"';
    echo $releases_html;
    echo '<h2>Songs for "'.$term->name.'"';
    echo $songs_html;
    echo '<h2>Pages for "'.$term->name.'"';
    echo $pages_html;
}
```

This approach uses only one query request and thus is resources friendly.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness, but it seems that I am not 100% sure what I am doing or I am missing something fairly obvious.

I have added the first snippet to functions.php and the later to taxonomy-people.php and that crashed the entire website. 

I apologise if I'm being thick - I have not used this hook before.

Comment: There were some typos in my code - feel free to grab it again ;). For the case your entire page goes down (not just this time, ever) - try to set WP_DEBUG true in you wp-config.php ( see https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG )

Comment: Now I'm getting entire posts, but the basics are there - thank you. I guess I'll modify $posts_html, $pages_html and the other two to only show the titles and permalinks and that should be it.

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: You're right - modify those variables in a way you need...

Comment: I am not sure how to output the permalink instead of h3 and how to get The Name instead of the-name to show.

Comment: see modified answer above

Comment: You're welcome. Mark the answer as correct, if you can ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have taxonomy people, and people like Bobby Lee, Michael Jordan, Matt Mullenweg.

whenever someone goes to the page: http://domain.tld/people/bobby-lee, he will get all the posts that are in that taxonomy. No matter the post type.

Iva said:

> I don't know how to get WP_Query to show only results for the current term WITHOUT having to make a specific template for each of the terms

If you go to: http://etfovac.com/tehnologije/torenti/ You will see that taxonomy tehnologije spans two post types (tutorials and wordpress) and that both are being displayed for the term **torenti** in the **tehnologije** taxonomy.

Therefore, my response is: Do not mess with WP_Query. Default Query will pull all the posts that contain specific term.

Answer (score -2):

Don't use WP_Query, use query_posts instead to modify the query.

WP_Query overrides everything.

Comment: @SeeBeen I think you have your logic mixed up. If you want to make new queries you should always use `new WP_Query` not `query_posts()`

Comment: The point is that she shouldn't use new Query