# Listing custom post type items from a couple of custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop, query

I know I have asked a similar question in the recent past (**[Listing all custom post types using a specific term on the said term's template page, in groups](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85367/listing-all-custom-post-types-using-a-specific-term-on-the-said-terms-template/)**), but in this case, the template is more complicated.

This is what I have on a website's front page.

```
<!---Front page videos-->
<div class="twelve columns clearfix" id="clips">
<!---Code to output front page videos-->
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$the_query = query_posts(
    array(
        'post_type'=>'video',
        'posts_per_page'=>90,
        'orderby'=>'date',
        'paged'=>$paged
    )
);
// ...
?>
```

" >
    
        
            " rel="bookmark">
             'front-thumb') ); else { ?>
         

          
            " title="" rel="bookmark">
            
        

        

             
                
                    ID, 'jetpack-post-views', true ); ?> 
                 
                ', '' ); ?>
            
        
    



'; $count = 0; } else $count++; ?>

Either by using just this template or creating a couple of others, I'm supposed to output results from four different taxonomies called video-categories. How do I do that? I have tried to fix the code I was given two months ago in the linked question, but I was getting errors.

This would more or less save me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What errors did you get? Also, please try to format your code better.

Comment: Hello,

I am not sure how to format it right, everything goes wrong.

I get the same listing of ALL custom post type items on each page. That's the issue.